# FOSS and selfhosted alternative to Endnote/Zotero

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, research

Presently, I am using [Endnote](http://endnote.com/) however this does not operate on Android (iOS is available). I am looking for a **self-hosted** alternative for EndNote.

#### Requirements

I am looking for a reference manager that:

1. Has a native Android client.
2. Has free (gratis) options to extend storage, preferably at a self-hosted location.

#### Nice to have

1. Open source
2. Can automatically add references based on identifier (DOI, ISBN, etc...).
3. Has a browser plugin to import items from the web.
4. Can link one or more documents to a reference.
5. Allows for tagging and/or a folder structure.
6. Allows for collaboration through shared reference collections or similar, while using the free self-hosted storage.

#### Things I've looked into.

For those wondering, I have created a [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) account (covers most requirements) and they offer [WebDAV](https://www.zotero.org/support/sync#webdav) functionality allowing to use self-hosted storage. Unfortunately, as for groups [the WebDAV functionality is not available](https://github.com/zotero/zotero/issues/294) and you're limited to the 300mb of the free plan.

I have a VPS so are there any alternatives to Endnote/Zotero that is FOSS and has the ability to be self-hosted?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I've gone and edited your question to make it more readable, and friendly. As I was unawares as to what Endnote did, I went and added a hyperlink for others. Just a thought, have you looked at http://incubator.rockefeller.edu/reference-manager-round-up-alternatives-to-endnote/ ?

Comment: Moreover, https://www.colwiz.com/home seems appropriate however is **not** self hosted...2GB free space for transactions.

Comment: Thanks to Michaels edit we get a bit closer – but still need to check other sites to figure what your question is about. Please take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) to see what's missing, then [edit] your question and fill the gaps. Dramatically increases your chances for good answers, as people otherwise often simply "skip over" if they don't get the idea. So apart from "being hosted", what must the software do?

Comment: You can [use WebDAV](https://www.zotero.org/support/sync) with Zotero.  Can you meet your needs by self-hosting a WebDAV server and syncing Zotero to that?

Comment: @saaru-lindestøkke I did my best to include your recent edits without excluding any recommendations that would fit the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion does not address all requirements, but as it addresses most I'm posting it as an answer.

[JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) with a [shared Postgres/Oracle/MySQL database](https://docs.jabref.org/collaborative-work/sqldatabase) and a network storage (both on a self-hosted VPS) is an option. I've listed how it address the requirements below:

1. Has a native Android client - **unfortunately not.**
2. Has free (gratis) options to extend storage, preferably at a self-hosted location. - Yes.

---

1. Open source - Yes, [code is hosted here](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref)
2. Can automatically add references based on identifier (DOI, ISBN, etc...). - [Yes](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/getbibtexdatafromdoi)
3. Has a browser plugin to import items from the web. - [Yes](https://docs.jabref.org/collect/jabref-browser-extension)
4. Can link one or more documents to a reference. - [Yes](https://docs.jabref.org/v/v4/fields/filelinks)
5. Allows for tagging and/or a folder structure. - Yes, it has [groups](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/groups)
6. Allows for collaboration through shared reference collections or similar, while using the free self-hosted storage. - Yes, by using the aforementioned shared database in combination with a library specific [General file location](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/filelinks#directories-for-files) on a network share.

One downside: the application is utterly slow (at least version 5.2 and 5.3). Editing an entry is almost unworkable due to the huge typing delay. Perhaps i's only when using the shared configuration with a network drive.
The issue is known and tracked [here](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/5071).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution came up (no Android client though): [ZotPrime v2](https://github.com/uniuuu/zotprime/tree/v2.3.4-beta). It is a fork of [ZotPrime](https://github.com/FiligranHQ/zotprime) and creates a self-hosted instance of Zotero 6 using Docker. It also allows you to build your own Zotero client pointing to your own self-hosted server.

I have not experimented with it yet, but it looks promising!