# selfhosted reference manager

Tags: reference-management

This may have been asked before and I keep searching from time to time but never find something truly useful. Are there any free or paid software managers that can be self hosted? by that I mean self host the database and the collection of articles. The ability to be able to create accounts for users to be able to work collaboratively is also important and to make it perfect an android client would be amazing. But I know I am asking too much!

I know `zotero` exists but it is lacking the self host ability and the android client. They really push their storage which I don't find useful and quite expensive for what they offer.

I found a github project called `cloudref` but it appears abandoned since 2019.

Does anyone know of a good self hosted reference manager? It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 0):

There was a somewhat similar question on here some years ago: [FOSS and selfhosted alternative to Endnote/Zotero](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48335/foss-and-selfhosted-alternative-to-endnote-zotero)

At the time, no option that fits all your requirements was mentioned. Still: Zotero should be able to [sync via WebDAV](https://www.zotero.org/support/sync#webdav)—have you had a chance to try it out? Ideally, you could set up Zotero so that it uses a/your WebDAV server for storage and then you can use any of the Android apps to access everything.